# Scala IntelliJ IDEA with sbt, gen-idea error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have created a project directory structure like below.

```
projecMyPro/
       src/
          main/
              scala/
                   Mymain.scala
```

In `Mymain.scala` I have created a simple Hello world object.

then I ran sbt and gen-idea.(I had already created a `/.sbt/0.13/plugins/build.sbt` file and sbt plugin for idea)

It created a .idea dir.

When I open it through idea and run the project it shows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  Wrong arguments: [scala.tools.nsc.CompileClient] 
  at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.rt.ClassRunner.main(ClassRunner.java:30)
```

Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: Probably your Scala compiler in IDEA is not correctly set up. Did you create a Run Configuration for your project? Is this the first time you use IDEA? You might need to define a Java SDK first, I am not sure this is done automatically. `Project Structure -> SDKs -> +`. Finally, are you able to build your project, i.e. is the error only appearing when you try to run it?

Comment: When I create a normal scala project with idea it builds and runs successfully. But when I build it with sbt gen-idea and import it to IDEA it does not run and gives above error.

Comment: Have you tried importing your project with IntelliJ IDEA 13 directly? It supports `Import Project` now where you point to your sbt file. Still has some quirks, but I have successfully used it a few times.